# At what point does the Optimal Decision Tree stop splitting in SAS Entreprise Miner?

Tags: machine-learning, sas, decision-tree

I am trying to understand the difference between Maximal Decision Tree and Optimal Decision Tree. In my understanding, the Maximal Decision Tree stops splitting when the log value of the variables become 0. I would like to know at what point the Optimal Decision Tree decides to stop splitting?